# Sharing code between Xamarin forms and ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET 4.6.1) projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET 4.6.1) project I have switch out an older PCL project used to share code with a Xamarin project with a new .NET standard 2 project (because the Xamarin project is now a Xamarin forms 3.2 project).

The ASP.NET MVC 5 compiles without errors, but gives the following warning:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5):

Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Concurrent" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

... the list of assemblyBinding nodes continue.

Is the solution to add each of the listed assemblyBinding xml nodes to the web.config > configuration > runtime section?

References

**Shared Projects code sharing**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows

**Sharing code overview**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing

Comment: Do you try add the assemblyBinding xml nodes to the web.config > configuration > runtime section?

Answer (score 0):

I added the listed 52 assemblies into the section  and the warning is gone.

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Concurrent" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```